# How to use jquery in a external .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website, there include such 2 files: index.php, script.js
Of course, it is much more complicated in the web site and the above only shows a part of it.

In index.php, there is a div element

```
<div id="phb29" class="drag ph hour01">Testing</div>
```

In script.js,which is a pure javascipt file,below show a part that i want to use a jquery function .switchClass() (from http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) to switch the class of div element.

```
//... other normal js codes

switchClassHour = function(){

    $(function (){       
            $( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 );
                return false;
        });     
}

//other normal js codes...
```

I only want to call that jquery when I call the switchClassHour() function but not the web page is loaded(i.e. $(document).ready(function (){...}); )

I have included the source in the  in index.php:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

But finally, the chrome browser gives me this error occurring at the line $(function (){   when I trigger switchClassHour():

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function
```

What should I do, thank you !!!!! :):)

Comment: you should create a function to load jquery (create a script element) and  a callback (event after jquery is loaded) to the switchClassHour function ... then you could remove the `$(function (){...});` from switchClassHour (the real cause of your error)

Comment: Are there any example for my reference to create that function and callback? I'm sorry that I'm just a beginner of js and jq!
Thx for answering my question!!!:)

Comment: So you don't want to load jQuery until you have a function that requires it? Is that what you're asking? Because if that is the case then what rafaelcastrocouto said is correct and you should just generate a `<script>` tag with the link to jQuery when call that method. There are then further optimization questions such as how do you determine if jQuery is already loaded so you don't load it again.

Comment: Here is an example for you http://jsbin.com/bupat/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `toHour` does not appear to be defined within the function `switchClassHour`.

Try this

```
switchClassHour = function(){
/* `toHour` ? */
  if (window.jQuery) {
    /* $(function (){  */     
            $( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 );
                /* `return false;` ? */
    /*    }); */
  };    
};
switchClassHour(); /* just noticed, is the function actually called ? */
```

Edit

Try this

```
   switchClassHour = function(){
    /* `toHour` ? */
      if (window.jQuery) {
        /* $(function (){  */     
                console.log($.now())
                    /* `return false;` ? */
        /*    }); */
      };    
    };
    switchClassHour();
```

Is `$.now()` return'ed at console?

Is `$` utilized in other parts of non-jquery pieces?

See also https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Edit

Try this

```
switchClassHour = function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
     console.log($.now(), jQuery.now())
  })(jQuery);
};switchClassHour();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The line "console.log($.now())" trigger error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'now' ".
Also I think $ is not utilized in other parts of non-jquery pieces.
Thank you for helping me! much appreciate.

Comment: OMG!! You totally solve my problem!!!!I changed "console.log($.now(), jQuery.now())" into "$( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 );". Then, the effect is executed! Big thanks!Cheers~:D

Answer (score 0):

```
function switchClassHour(){
    if(document.getElementById('jq')){
        //original switchClassHour() code. 
    }
    else{
        var jq = document.createElement('script');
        jq.src = "WHATEVER SOURCE YOU WANT TO LOAD FROM (PROBABLY GOOGLE)";
        jq.id = "jq";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendNode(jq);
        //Original switchClassHour() code
   }
}
```

I don't know if this is guaranteed to work since I don't know if you'll be able to load jQuery fast enough to call your function immediately afterwards. If this doesn't work because jQuery isn't loading fast enough then the only outcome I could see is adding a delay but that's ugly. To be honest if you're using jQuery I would just load it from Google normally in the `<head>` of your page. Most people have it cached already.

Comment: I do this in switchClassHour() but same error occurs at $( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 ); from the else-statement. Below are my code in switchClassHour():

  if(document.getElementById('jq')){
     $( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 );
  }else{
  var jq = document.createElement('script');
  jq.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js";
  jq.id = "jq";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
  $( "#phb29" ).switchClass( "hour01", "hour03", 1000 );
  }

Comment: It gives "Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function " at the line of switching class(in else statement).
In addition, the line you provided "document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendNode(jq);" will trigger error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLHeadElement>" has no method 'appendNode' ". So I changed as above shown.